# How to fix a capitalized Salesforce 18-Digit ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce

If a Salesforce 18 digit ID is returned (say, by a third-party program) in an all-capital format, this renders the 18 digit ID unreadable by Salesforce. How can I use python to fix this all-capital ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is a reconstruction of the question "[Converting uppercased 18-digit Id to valid Id" on the Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123217/converting-uppercased-18-digit-id-to-valid-id/241090#241090)". The solution posted here converts Adrian Larson's solution to repairing the upcase ID from APEX to Python 3.

APEX solution converted to Python 3:

```
def getBitPatterns(c):
    CHARS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345'
    index = CHARS.find(c)
    result = []
    for bitNumber in range(0,5):
        result.append((index & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0)
    return result

def repairCasing(x18DigitId):
    if len(x18DigitId) < 18:
        return 'Error'
    toUpper = []
    toUpper.append(getBitPatterns(x18DigitId[15:16]))
    toUpper.append(getBitPatterns(x18DigitId[16:17]))
    toUpper.append(getBitPatterns(x18DigitId[17:18]))
    toUpper = [item for sublist in toUpper for item in sublist]

    output = ''.join([x18DigitId[x].upper() if toUpper[x] else x18DigitId[x].lower() for x in range(0,15)]) + x18DigitId[15:].upper()

    return output
```

Example:

```
repairCasing('003i000001IIGW7AAH')
```

Out:

```
'003i000001IIGw7AAH'
```

**Note:**

For learners,

`toUpper = [item for sublist in toUpper for item in sublist]`

is a list-comprehension method of flattening arrays within an array into a single array (credit to Alex Martinelli at [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)), and is the equivalent of:

```
for sublist in toUpper:
    for item in sublist:
        newList.append(item)
toUpper = newList
```

Similarly:

`output = ''.join([x18DigitId[x].upper() if toUpper[x] else x18DigitId[x].lower() for x in range(0,15)]) + x18DigitId[15:].upper()`

is the list-comprehension equivalent of:

```
     output = ''

     for i in range(0,15):
         c = x18DigitId[i:i+1]
         if toUpper[i]:
             output += c.upper()
         else:
             output += c.lower()

     output += x18DigitId[15:18].upper()
```